# Customise the template for Scaffolded Razor Pages (CRUD) in .net core 3.1 / Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2019

I've started a project using Razor Pages in .net-core 3.1, with Visual Studio 2019

I want to be able to modify the template, or create a project-specific version of the templates used to create CRUD Scaffolded pages - 'Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)'

I *can* find the scaffolding template pages for standard MVC, but I can't find the ones for Razor Pages anywhere. I'm sure it must be possible to update these so the created layouts match what you want from them, but I'm fairly new to .net-core and after several hours of searching have drawn a blank. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar question. Adding a new Scaffolded Razor Page (CRUD) to my Blazor App whatever option I use, data table is visible but the page is completely unformatted.

Wondering how the layout can be inherited from the Blazor App. Like for a new Razor Component.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them here for version 5.0.1

**%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\5.0.1\Templates\RazorPageGenerator**